# Sparql - Applying limiting criteria to predicates

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena

I'm fairly new to RDF / Sparql, so apologies for any incorrect terminology, and also for the fairly terrible example that follows:

Given the following RDF dataset:

```
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix e:     <http://www.example.com/#> .
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

e:Freemason a owl:Class .
e:Civilian a owl:Class .

e:Marty a e:Freemason .
e:Eugene a e:Freemason .
e:Mike a e:Freemason .
e:Alan a e:Freemason .

e:Paul a e:Civilian .

e:Marty foaf:knows e:Eugene .
e:Eugene foaf:knows e:Mike .
e:Eugene foaf:knows e:Paul .
e:Paul foaf:knows e:Alan .
```

I'm trying to identify friends-of-friends that `e:Marty` knows through other `e:Freemason`s only.

So:

- Marty knows Mike through Eugene, and they're all Freemason's so it's fine
- Marty knows Eugene, who has a Civilian friend Paul.  Paul has a Freemason friend Alan.  However, Marty doesn't have a "freemason only" path to Alan, so he should be excluded.

Here's the SPARQL query I have:

```
prefix e: <http://www.example.com/#>
prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT *
{
  <http://www.example.com/#Marty> foaf:knows+ ?target .
  ?target a e:Freemason .
}
```

This returns:

```
 http://www.example.com/#Eugene
 http://www.example.com/#Mike
 http://www.example.com/#Alan
```

Here, Alan is included as he matches the `is-a-freemason` criteria.

How I do modify the query to exclude Alan?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you right away, but I am almost sure that you cannot do this in a single query. If it _is_ possible, it would certainly be a fairly complex SPARQL query.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024413/finding-all-steps-in-property-path

Comment: I think Jeen is right; I don't think you can do this with a single sparql query.  I'd you are using an endpoint that supports querying over CONSTRUCTed data (I think dot net RDF does, but I don't know whether any other ones do) then this is a fairy simple query over constructed data.

Comment: You could do this with a query over CONSTRUCT-ed data though.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363199/how-to-get-a-concise-bounded-description-of-a-resource-with-sesame and some of the comments on my answer for some ideas.  Instead of a self isIRI property, you'd want a isSelfFreemason property.  It's a kind of rolification.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the solution in pure SPARQL, sorry.
In OpenLink Virtuoso's SPARQL-BI, the solution is [this query](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20e%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fkingsley.idehen.net%2FDAV%2Fhome%2Fkidehen%2FPublic%2FLinked%2520Data%2520Documents%2FTutorials%2Fclub-member-test.ttl%3E%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%09SELECT%20%3Forig%20%3Ftarget%20%0D%0A%09%09WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%7B%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%20%20%3Forig%20%20foaf%3Aknows%20%3Ftarget%20.%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%20%20%09%3Ftarget%20a%20e%3AFreemason%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%20%7D%20%0D%0A%09%7D%20%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20OPTION%20%28TRANSITIVE%2C%20T_IN%28%3Forig%29%2C%20T_OUT%28%3Ftarget%29%2C%20T_DISTINCT%2C%20T_MIN%281%29%29%20%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Forig%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%23Marty%3E%29%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)

```
prefix e: <http://www.example.com/#>
prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select * 
where
  {
    { select ?orig ?target 
      where
       { ?orig   foaf:knows ?target . 
         ?target a          e:Freemason .
       } 
    } 
    option ( TRANSITIVE, 
             T_IN(?orig), 
             T_OUT(?target), 
             T_DISTINCT, 
             T_MIN(1)
           )
    filter ( ?orig = <http://www.example.com/#Marty> )
  }
```

-- with [these results](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20e%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fkingsley.idehen.net%2FDAV%2Fhome%2Fkidehen%2FPublic%2FLinked%2520Data%2520Documents%2FTutorials%2Fclub-member-test.ttl%3E%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%09SELECT%20%3Forig%20%3Ftarget%20%0D%0A%09%09WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%7B%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%20%20%3Forig%20%20foaf%3Aknows%20%3Ftarget%20.%20%0D%0A%09%09%09%20%20%09%3Ftarget%20a%20e%3AFreemason%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%20%7D%20%0D%0A%09%7D%20%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20OPTION%20%28TRANSITIVE%2C%20T_IN%28%3Forig%29%2C%20T_OUT%28%3Ftarget%29%2C%20T_DISTINCT%2C%20T_MIN%281%29%29%20%20%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Forig%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%23Marty%3E%29%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000) --

```
orig                               target
<http://www.example.com/#Marty>    <http://www.example.com/#Eugene>
<http://www.example.com/#Marty>    <http://www.example.com/#Mike>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using SPARQL that has been deprecated from the spec (for reasons I never understood) but remains supported in Virtuoso (which will be the case for the unforeseeable future)

```
## RDF-Turtle Start ##

@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix e:     <http://www.example.com/#> .
@prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

e:Freemason a owl:Class .
e:Civilian a owl:Class .

e:Marty a e:Freemason .
e:Eugene a e:Freemason .
e:Mike a e:Freemason .
e:Alan a e:Freemason .

e:Paul a e:Civilian .

e:Marty foaf:knows e:Eugene .
e:Eugene foaf:knows e:Mike .
e:Eugene foaf:knows e:Paul .
e:Paul foaf:knows e:Alan .

## RDF-Turtle End ##
```

### Using Property Path Pattern from SPARQL that has been deprecated

### but preserved in Virtuoso

```
PREFIX e: <http://kingsley.idehen.net/DAV/home/kidehen/Public/Linked%20Data%20Documents/Tutorials/club-member-test.ttl#>
PREFIX dsn: <http://kingsley.idehen.net/DAV/home/kidehen/Public/Linked%20Data%20Documents/Tutorials/club-member-test.>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
    
SELECT *
FROM dsn:ttl
WHERE {
       e:Marty foaf:knows{2} ?target .
       ?target a e:Freemason .
      }
```

Live Links:

1. [Query Solution](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+e%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fkingsley.idehen.net%2FDAV%2Fhome%2Fkidehen%2FPublic%2FLinked%2520Data%2520Documents%2FTutorials%2Fclub-member-test.ttl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dsn%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fkingsley.idehen.net%2FDAV%2Fhome%2Fkidehen%2FPublic%2FLinked%2520Data%2520Documents%2FTutorials%2Fclub-member-test.%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%0D%0ASELECT+*%0D%0AFROM+dsn%3Attl%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++++++e%3AMarty+foaf%3Aknows%7B2%7D+%3Ftarget+.%0D%0A+++++++%3Ftarget+a+e%3AFreemason+.%0D%0A++++++%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000000)
2. [Query Definition](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX+e%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fkingsley.idehen.net%2FDAV%2Fhome%2Fkidehen%2FPublic%2FLinked%2520Data%2520Documents%2FTutorials%2Fclub-member-test.ttl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dsn%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fkingsley.idehen.net%2FDAV%2Fhome%2Fkidehen%2FPublic%2FLinked%2520Data%2520Documents%2FTutorials%2Fclub-member-test.%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%0D%0ASELECT+*%0D%0AFROM+dsn%3Attl%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++++++e%3AMarty+foaf%3Aknows%7B2%7D+%3Ftarget+.%0D%0A+++++++%3Ftarget+a+e%3AFreemason+.%0D%0A++++++%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000000)