# Recursive SPARQL query for a combination of triples

Tags: python, sparql, owl

I have the following query that I run recursively in Python using ontospy:

```
SELECT ?c WHERE {
    ?c rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
    ?restriction owl:onProperty :has_part ; owl:someValuesFrom ?p .
    VALUES ?p { <some_uri> }
}
```

Basically, I take the values returned from that and re-run the query to follow a hierarchy of "has part some" relationships within an ontology. I am hoping to avoid making multiple SPARQL queries by adding the recursion to the query itself. I know how to do this for a single triple using `rdfs:subClassOf*` but cannot figure out the syntax for combining the two triples:

```
?c rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
?restriction owl:onProperty :has_part ; owl:someValuesFrom ?p .
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Obviously, it is possible to write something like `(rdfs:subClassOf/owl:someValuesFrom)*`, however, in general, it is impossible in this way to specify that restrictions are on the `:has_part` property. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641984/sparql-applying-limiting-criteria-to-predicates) and linked ones, and also https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/PropertyPaths.

Comment: @StanislavKralin I see, thanks for the info. To quote The Dude, "That's a bummer, man!"

Comment: Please add the "python" tag if relevant.

Comment: Yep, was just thinking the same. Thanks for the answer, I'll look it over today. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't give a formal proof, but this looks impossible. This is not what property paths were designed for, and why some extensions exist ([1](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/PropertyPaths), [2](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlimplementatiotrans/)).

Under certain commitments (e.g. with tree-like structures), it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301893/how-to-check-for-a-sub-property-at-all-levels-expanded-from-a-sparql-wildcard) to figure out something using `FILTER NOT EXISTS`, however, this is not a general solution.

The idea is to do this in two queries. In essence, this is `SELECT` over `CONSTRUCT`. By the way, such SPARQL extension has already been [proposed](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-749/paper19.pdf).

---

Let's use [rdflib](/questions/tagged/rdflib) on which Ontospy is based, because

> Ontospy does not offer any ontology-editing features, nor it can be used to interrogate a triplestore.

**Input (`ontology.ttl`)**

```
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/ontology#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.example.org/ontology> .

<http://www.example.org/ontology> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:hasPart rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

:Country rdf:type owl:Class ;
         rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                           owl:onProperty :hasPart ;
                           owl:someValuesFrom :State
                         ] .

:State rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                         owl:onProperty :hasPart ;
                         owl:someValuesFrom :City
                       ] .

:City rdf:type owl:Class .
```

**Python code**

```python
import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("ontology.ttl", format="n3")

qres = g.update(
    """PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/ontology#> 
       INSERT { ?c :hasSome ?p } 
       WHERE  { ?c rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:onProperty :hasPart ; 
                                     owl:someValuesFrom ?p ] }""")

qres = g.query(
    """PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/ontology#> 
       SELECT ?a ?b WHERE {?a :hasSome+ ?b }""")

for row in qres:
    print("%s :hasSome+ %s" % row)

qres = g.update(
    """PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/ontology#> 
       DELETE { ?s :hasSome ?o } WHERE { ?s :hasSome ?o }""")
```

**Output**

```
:Country :hasSome+ :State
:State   :hasSome+ :City
:Country :hasSome+ :City
```

---

If you don't want to modify initial RDFLib graph, just create another one:

```python
import rdflib

g1 = rdflib.Graph()
g1.parse("ontology.ttl", format="n3")

qres = g1.query(
    """PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/ontology#> 
       CONSTRUCT {?c :hasSome ?p } WHERE {
           ?c rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:onProperty :hasPart ;
                                owl:someValuesFrom ?p  ] }""")

g2 = rdflib.Graph();
for triple in qres: # quite a few triples
    g2.add(triple)

qres = g2.query(
    """PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/ontology#> 
       SELECT ?a ?b WHERE { ?a :hasSome+ ?b }""")

for row in qres:
    print("%s :hasSome+ %s" % row)
```

Probably you can use [`transitiveClosure()`](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.graph.Graph.transitiveClosure) or [`transitive_objects()`](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.graph.Graph.transitive_objects) instead of the second query in both cases.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav, if no one else posts a better answer I'll award the bounty to this answer before it expires.

Comment: @Fiver, as you wish! Perhaps @AndyS[eaborn] can give a formal proof, or there is something like such proof in articles of Claudio Gutierrez. BTW, it seems that there are some problems in SPARQL formal semantics (see e.g. section 2 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01441.pdf)). Perhaps you could also ask you question at [public-sparql-dev](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-sparql-dev/)