# Restrict SPARQL property path predicates based on blank node attached meta / reified data

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdflib, propertypath

*I want to traverse graph starting from any "root" concept and getting down to its leaf concepts moving by **reified** predicates of **certain type** (e.g. `hasChild` only).*

I have a large graph in which Concepts `C` are connected with named predicates `R`.
Predicates are in turn attached to blank nodes `B` which hold their meta data, including connection type `CT`.

Essentially the pattern is:

```
root_concept -[^subject]-> blank -[object]-> concept -[^subject]-> blank -[object]-> concept -[^subject]-> blank -[object]-> ...
```

And I want to get all downstream concepts. 
So normally you would do something like (1):

```
SELECT ?c
WHERE { 
  FILTER(  ?root = <SomeValue>  ) .
  ?root (^rdf:subject/rdf:object)* ?c .
}
```

But I need to get intermediate blank node `B` and filter on its `CT`!
For a single step this looks like (2):

```
SELECT ?c
WHERE { 
  FILTER(  ?root = <SomeValue>  ) .
  ?root  ^rdf:subject ?blank .
  ?blank  rdf:object  ?c .
  ?blank  :hasRelationType    "hasChild" .
}
```

**Question**: How to merry (1) and (2)?

Additional info:

Each blank node has at least these triples:

```
1   blank1  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type     http://some/ontology/terms/Relationship
3   blank1  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#object   C2
4   blank1  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#predicate    R
5   blank1  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#subject  C1
6   blank1  http://some/ontology/terms/hasRelationType      NotHasChild (!)
```

Predicates represented by `blank` nodes B actually have their own IDs, but they are completely uninformative (i.e. `rdf:predicate` from blank nodes leads to something like `R0134235`)

I have tried modeling my query based on [arbitrary length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65493413/sparql-arbitrary-length-property-path-query-with-arbitrary-but-directed-properti) property paths, and general recipe for [getting all child properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241812/sparql-query-to-get-all-triples-related-to-a-specific-subject), but couldn't figure that out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38641984, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352066

Comment: I see, so I either need to introduce `tmp` predicates or use smth like SPARQL-BI. I would like to try the second approach, but the only tutorial for `~BI` I have found (http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/DAV/virtuoso2.openlinksw.com/content/sparql-tutorials.html) does not load for some reason.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if adding `tmp` predicates would be more efficient (and safer) than just running queries recursively given that the subgraph is of decent size (millions of nodes) and is part of a much larger graph.