# SPARQL Property path for all properties of certain type

Tags: properties, sparql, semantic-web

I want to a query to load a resource and automatically load all resources connected by a 'DependencyProperty'.

The query below does what I want up to 3 levels deep. I'm wondering if it can be altered - potentially with property paths? - in such a way that there is no limit to how deep it goes.

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
    :resourceToLoad ?p ?o.
    OPTIONAL { 
        ?p rdf:type :DependencyProperty.
        ?o ?p2 ?o2.
        OPTIONAL { 
            ?p2 rdf:type :DependencyProperty.
            ?o2 ?p3 ?o3.
            OPTIONAL { 
                ?p3 rdf:type :DependencyProperty.
                ?o3 ?p4 ?o4.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38641984/7879193), then proceed to the linked ones...

Comment: that can't work with property paths because variables are not allowed in a property path. thus, a single query will not solve your problem

Comment: According to the answer, you're using inferencing, then please add tag that corresponds to your triplestore.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solution myself for now. I added

```
:DependencyProperty rdfs:subClassOf [
    a owl:Restriction;
    owl:onProperty rdfs:subPropertyOf;
    owl:hasValue :dependency;
]
```

now every property that is a `:DependencyProperty` is a subPropertyOf `:dependency`, so every time a dependency property appears as predicate in a triple, another triple is created with :dependency as predicate.

So now I can query like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE { {
    ?s?p ?o
    FILTER(?s= :resourceToLoad)
} UNION {
    :resourceToLoad :dependency+ ?s.
    ?s?p ?o.
}}
```

Comment: this works only for triples with the predicate being `:DependencyProperty` itself, but not for properties of type `:DependencyProperty` as you've asked for in your question - or am I wrong?

Comment: `:a :DependencyProperty :b .   -> :b  rdfs:subPropertyOf :dependency . ` - that follows from the range axiom.

Comment: Ah you're right, typo.. it should be rdfs:subClassOf instead of rdfs:range. That's way it works (and is how its working for me). `:a :p :b` & `:p rdf:type :DependencyProperty` => `:a :dependency :b`.